# Problem with HTML form button for submit data

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm writing a small site for my friend and I wanted to do an access log in page. I'm using: Html, Css, Angular and TypeScript with Bootstrap and swiper libraries. The submit button and the required attributes doens't works... I'm not understanding why. This is my TypeScript, CSS and HTML code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthappService } from '../services/authapp.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public postaE: string = "";
  public pwd: string = "";

  public nonAutenticato: boolean = false;
  public errMsg: string = "Spiacenti, posta elettronica o parola d'ordine errati."

  constructor(private route: Router, private authAdminTemp: AuthappService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

   loginAdmin = () : void => {
    console.log(this.postaE);
    console.log(this.pwd);

    if(this.authAdminTemp.autenticazioneTemp(this.postaE, this.pwd)) {
      this.route.navigate(['admin', this.postaE]);
      this.nonAutenticato = true;
    } else {
      this.nonAutenticato = false;
    }
  } 
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

main {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    place-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #99004d 0%, #ff0080 100%);
}

::selection {
    background: #ff80bf;

}

.container {
    background: #fff;
    max-width: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.container form .title {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.container form .title:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    width: 33px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #99004d 0%, #ff0080 100%);
}

.container form .input-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

.container form .input-box input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.container form .underline::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.container form .underline::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #99004d 0%, #ff0080 100%);
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.container form .input-box input:focus~.underline::after,
.container form .input-box input:valid~.underline::after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
}

.container form .button {
    margin: 40px 0 20px 0;
}

.container .input-box input[type="submit"] {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #99004d 0%, #ff0080 100%);
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.container .input-box input[type="submit"]:hover {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #99004d 0%, #ff0080 100%);
}

.ForgetPwd {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ForgetPwd:hover {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="container">
      <form action="" method="POST"> <!-- Imposto il metodo di trasferimento e l'azione svolta -->
          <div class="title">Accesso amministratore - Bentornato</div>
          <div class="input-box underline">
              <input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="postaE" placeholder="Posta elettronica..." required>
              <div class="underline"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
              <input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="pwd" placeholder="Chiave di accesso..." required>
              <div class="underline"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <a href="#" class="ForgetPwd">Parola chiave dimenticata?</a>
          </div>
          <div class="input-box button">
              <input type="submit" name="accedi" (click)="loginAdmin()" value="Continua">
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf='nonAutenticato'>
    {{errMsg}}
  </div>
</main>
```

Why the required attributes and submit button doesn't works ? Thank You for all ! Have a nice day !

Comment: What do you mean by "they don't work"?

Comment: Following the tutorial I saw that by inserting the "required" in the input tag and not inserting any value, the browse automatically generates a request to insert the data in the fields not filled in. In my case this does not happen ... I thought it was an Angular problem but I did not find any inconvenience from the code.

Comment: Making a template-driven form input `required` simply means the form isn't considered as valid as long as that field is empty. It doesn't automatically display an error message. (Also, the form tag's `action` and `method` attributes are unnecessary in Angular)

Comment: I understand... I was actually convinced of the opposite. I thought that by inserting the "required" attributes the browser would automatically disable the button ... Meanwhile I read some online guides and I found the solution to my problem. Thanks equally and I apologize for the now obsolete question.

Comment: No worries! That's what questions are for :)

Comment: Thank You very mach for help ! :-)